# How would nuclear fuel enriched with oxygen 18 behave in a reactor?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

A lot of nuclear reactors use fuel based on uranium oxides (mostly dioxide). I know that [oxygen 18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxide) has a slightly smaller neutron-capture cross section than the other stable isotopes. I  wondered whether that small difference is enough to improve the probability of Uranium interaction, I  mean that if $^{18}$O had a higher proportion it would interfere less with the neutrons around.

Would that have an impact on the critical mass and other parameters of current commercial nuclear reactors? Or would the difference be negligible?

I would like to know what would be the change if $^{18}$O were enriched to about 20% and what would happen if $^{18}$O were enriched to about 40%.

Note: I know that isotope separation is expensive, but this question is not about the economy. I would only like to know the physical behaviour regardless of the cost.

Note2: With an initial search I found this [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8600625/), but it mainly deals with the fuel production process.

Note 3: since scientist and engineers found out that pure uranium was difficult to use in a nuclear reactor they began to look for alloying and cladding materials with a low neutron-capture cross section that could be used to improve the physical properties without altering too much the nuclear properties of the fissile materials. That is why eventually they started using oxygen (and zirconium for the cladding). I asked this question because I wanted to know if there was room for further improvement, it is not something a absurd as the only answer posted at the moment suggests. (at least for now, I still didn't get to the isotope separation of Zirconium :) ).

Comment: @JonCuster I don't get you. What do biological processes have to do with this question? I know that Oxygen 18 has a slightly lower neutron interaction cross section than Oxygen 16 or Oxygen 17. That has nothing to do with biological processes.

Comment: Related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/727810/250611

Answer (score 3):

Going over to ENDF ([at BNL](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/endf/) or your preferred local alternative mirror) and looking at neutron cross sections in the thermal to several-MeV range (most fission neutrons are around 2MeV initially), one sees that $^{18}$O is not particularly exciting. The total cross section is $<10$ barns, and there is a slight chance (one in a million) of making an $^{19}$O with a gamma released.

In comparison, $^{16}$O has a similar total cross section, and a higher probability of absorbing a neutron to make $^{17}$O. That is about it. Since the neutron properties of oxygen do not have a major impact on fission reactor operations, the use of $^{18}$O does not change the behavior.

I will note that oxygen is not required for a fission reactor. A recent review of early nuclear piles (B. Cameron Reed in [European Physical Journal H](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjh/s13129-021-00020-x)) shows these early critical reactors:

CP-1 (Chicago), a mix of pure U and uranium oxide.

CP-2 (Argonne), made by moving CP-1 out of Chicago, was run with pure U to get data for Hanford.

X-10 (Oak Ridge), pure Uranium fuel.

LOPO (Los Alamos) used uranium sulfate in solution in water. First to use isotopically enriched uranium.

HYPO (Las Alamos) used uranyl nitrate in solution.

Hanford B, D, and F all used uranium metal.

Note also that various uranium oxides were used in different reactors.

Comment: I thought it was obvious. Oxygen here is used just because pure uranium is not chemically stable enough. But oxygen must not interfere with the nuclear reaction. My question asked what would happen if we further reduced the ability of oxygen to interfere. Is it so difficult to understand?

Comment: @FluidCode - what makes you think that oxygen has any major impact on the nuclear reactions? The different isotopes scatter neutrons a little differently, that is all. Clearly you think something else may go on, so clarify your concerns. Note that bare-metal highly enriched uranium reactors are well known (see Godiva) - oxygen is not required at all.