# Would isotope separation of zirconium improve the effectiveness of nuclear fuel?

Tags: nuclear-engineering

Zirconium is widely used as cladding for nuclear fuel for two reasons, it is a good refractory material and it has a low neutron-capture cross section. I was wondering if, at least theoretically,  there is room for improvement. I know that isotope separation now is impractical, but I would like to skip this point for the moment.

if, instead of using the current mix of different isotopes, we could pick the zirconium isotopes with the lowest neutron-capture cross section would it make a difference? Would it affect the main parameters of the current commercial nuclear reactors and how?  Or, would the change be negligible?

Comment: Of the 4 stable isotopes, 90Zr has the lowest absorption cross section - that is for the 90Zr(n,g)91Zr reactions, I'm ignoring (n,anything else) reactions. For low energy neutrons it is under 1 barn. The highest is 91Zr with the 91Zr(n,g)92Zr reaction having a cross section o just under 100 barns. 90Zr is the most common isotope, 91Zr the least common stable isotope. For comparison, the cross section for the 1H(n,g)2H reaction is over 10 barns, and the fission cross section for 235U is about 40,000 barns.

Comment: Related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/726680/250611